# Closing a form when other form is opening

Tags: c#, winforms

The current problem is that the "mainScreen" shows up, but immediately closes, I have no idea why. This is the piece of code that handles the close and opening of the new form.

Edit: .this refers to Login.cs (sorry)

```
 if(templogin == true && permission.Equals("1"))
 {
                mainScreen.IsAdmin();
                this.Close();
                mainScreen.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Comment: why would like to call Close if you want it to show?

Comment: I want to close the current screen, but open a new screen (which will be the Main screen of the application).

Comment: `Application.Run()` in `Program.cs` is probably relying on the `this` window, once that form closes the application ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you should not close the application(as login form seems main form while you started the application) before another form run:
Do like this :

```
if(templogin == true && permission.Equals("1"))
 {
                this.Hide();
                mainScreen.IsAdmin();
                mainScreen.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();

 }
```

Comment: Using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` is probably better.

Comment: Yeah, I used to use ShowDialog for login form and other form as Show

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run 2 forms (switching from one to another), then you should do it in `Main`

Instead of

```
Application.Run(new StartupForm());
```

you'll have to use

```
var startup = new StartupForm();
startup.ShowDialog();
if(somecondition) // when StartupForm is closed and return something (or property is set, etc)
{
    var main = new MainScreen();
    main.ShowDialog();
}
```

You don't need `Application.Run` at all when using `ShowDialog`.

Comment: I'd still use `Application.Run(main)` inside the condition instead of `main.ShowDialog()` to have access to `Application.*` events, but yes, this would work.

Comment: @Jcl, good idea. Though I have hard time to imagine which events are needed once you start manually control program flow.

Comment: `ThreadExit`, `ThreadException`, etc. , also, you'd have access to `OpenForms` and other utilities (like `UseWaitCursor`, etc.), which don't work if you don't have an `ApplicationContext` and use the message loop that `ShowDialog` opens. Mind you: `ShowDialog` **works** and I'm not saying otherwise... but `Application` and `ApplicationContext` have some very nice utilities to use, at the same cost (it'd also support several non-modal forms [using `Application.Run()` with no parameters after `Show`ing the forms] without it having to be a single parent).

Comment: @Jcl, interesting, thanks. I know about `OpenForms`, never thought if it will *require* `Application.Run` to work (because I never used it myself, always prefer other ways to access forms). Problem is what as soon as you do `Application.Run` you can't control flow anymore after. Or can you? Second `Application.Run` call?

Comment: No, you can't, but you can't either using `ShowDialog`. `Application.Run()` blocks until you call `Application.Exit()`, same as `ShowDialog()` blocks until the form is closed. If you call `Application.Run(form)` then it'll block just the same (and will continue executing till the form closes). I'm not sure if you can call `Application.Run()` without parameters several times, but you definitely can create other `ApplicationContext`s manually.and call `Application.Run()` passing them as parameters (specifying a `MainForm` on the context if you wish).